# Big white Space on the right side On Screen Size 767px and Below Bootstrap responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, screen-size

I'm having some issues with a bootstrap responsive screen size, for some reason when the window is smaller than 767px there is around 30px or larger  padding on the right and I have no idea how to get rid of it. if screen size is smaller, the white bar in the right size is bigger. Could you please give me a hand? 
[Here is a link for files](https://gist.github.com/ymphyow/e84c950ad299125cc50af471986df311)

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33fXk.png)
Bootstrap.responsive

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
  body {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom,
  .navbar-static-top {
    margin-right: -20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
  }
  .container-fluid {
    padding: 0
  }
  .dl-horizontal dt {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    clear: none;
    text-align: left
  }
  .dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 0
  }
  .container {
    width: auto
  }
  .row-fluid {
    width: 100%
  }
  .row,
  .thumbnails {
    margin-left: 0
  }
  .thumbnails>li {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0
  }
  [class*="span"],
  .uneditable-input[class*="span"],
  .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
  }
  .span12,
  .row-fluid .span12 {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
  }
  .row-fluid [class*="offset"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0
  }
  .input-large,
  .input-xlarge,
  .input-xxlarge,
  input[class*="span"],
  select[class*="span"],
  textarea[class*="span"],
  .uneditable-input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
  }
  .input-prepend input,
  .input-append input,
  .input-prepend input[class*="span"],
  .input-append input[class*="span"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto
  }
  .controls-row [class*="span"]+[class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 0
  }
  .modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0
  }
  .modal.fade {
    top: -100px
  }
  .modal.fade.in {
    top: 20px
  }
}

@media(max-width:480px) {
  .nav-collapse {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  }
  .page-header h1 small {
    display: block;
    line-height: 20px
  }
  input[type="checkbox"],
  input[type="radio"] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc
  }
  .form-horizontal .control-label {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    text-align: left
  }
  .form-horizontal .controls {
    margin-left: 0
  }
  .form-horizontal .control-list {
    padding-top: 0
  }
  .form-horizontal .form-actions {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px
  }
  .media .pull-left,
  .media .pull-right {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px
  }
  .media-object {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0
  }
  .modal {
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px
  }
  .modal-header .close {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: -10px
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    position: static
  }
}
```

Main.CSS

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);
.clearfix{*zoom:1}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after{
 display:table;
 content:"";
 line-height:0
 }
.clearfix:after{
 clear:both
 }
.hide-text{
 font:0/0 a;
 color:transparent;
 text-shadow:none;
 background-color:transparent;
 border:0
 }
.input-block-level{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 min-height:30px;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box
 }

body{
 padding-top:80px;
 font-size:12px;
 color:#34495e;
 background:#f5f5f5
 width:100%;
}
body h1,body h2,body h3,body h4,body 
.created{
 font-family:"Fjalla One";
 font-weight:normal
 }
body h5{margin:0}
body h3,body h4{margin-top:0}
body h6{margin:0;font-family:"roboto_thregular"; font-size: "24px"}
body 
.btn{
 -webkit-border-radius:0;
 -moz-border-radius:0;
 border-radius:0;
 border:0;
 background-image:none;
 text-shadow:none;
 -webkit-box-shadow:none;
 -moz-box-shadow:none;
 box-shadow:none
 }
 .btn.btn-transparent{
  border:3px solid #fff;
  background:transparent;
  color:#fff
  }
 .btn.btn-transparent:hover{ border-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)}
 .btn.btn-link{color:#bb0300;padding:0}
 .btn.btn-link:hover{text-decoration:none}
 .btn-primary{background-color:#bb0300}
 .btn-primary:hover{background-color:#ff0200}
 a{color:#bb0300;-webkit-transition:300ms;-moz-transition:300ms;-o-transition:300ms;transition:300ms}
 a:hover,
 a:focus{color:#ff0200;text-decoration:none;outline:0}
 .dropdown-menu{margin-top:-1px;min-width:180px; color:#bb0300 }
 body>section{padding:5px 0}
 body>section
 #slide-show{padding:0}
 #recent-works{background:#bb0300;color:#fff}
 #recent-works .links>a{background:#fff;color:#bb0300;text-shadow:none}
 #clients{background:#fff}
 #clients h4{color:#999}
 #clients .carousel{margin-bottom:0}
 #clients .clients ul.thumbnails{margin:0}
 #clients .clients ul.thumbnails>li{text-align:center;margin-bottom:0}
 #clients .prev,
 #clients .next{color:#999}
 .title{background:#bb0000;color:#fff;padding:20px 0}
 .center{text-align:center}
 .box{
  background-color:#fff;
  border-top:1px solid #f0f0f0;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow:0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  border-radius:4px
  }
 .progress{margin-bottom:10px}
 .progress,.progress .bar{
  -webkit-border-radius:0;
  -moz-border-radius:0;
  border-radius:0;
  background-image:none;
  -webkit-box-shadow:none;
  -moz-box-shadow:none;
  box-shadow:none;
  text-shadow:none;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px
  }
 .label,.badge{font-weight:300;font-size:90%}
 ul.breadcrumb{margin:12px 0 0;background:transparent}
 ul.breadcrumb>li{text-shadow:none}
 ul.breadcrumb>li>a,ul.breadcrumb>li .divider{color:#fff}
 ul.breadcrumb>li.active{color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7)}
 ul.tag-cloud li{display:inline-block;margin:0 0 2px 0}
 .btn-social{border:0;color:#fff;text-shadow:0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)}
 .btn-social.btn-facebook{background:#4f7dd4}
 .btn-social.btn-facebook:hover{background:#789bde}
 .btn-social.btn-twitter{background:#5bceff}
 .btn-social.btn-twitter:hover{background:#8eddff}
 .btn-social.btn-linkedin{background:#21a6d8}
 .btn-social.btn-linkedin:hover{background:#49b9e3}
 .btn-social.btn-google-plus{background:#dc422b}
 .btn-social.btn-google-plus:hover{background:#e36957}
 .btn-social:hover{color:#fff}
 header.navbar .navbar-inner{ 
  background:#fff!important;
  border:0;
  -webkit-box-shadow:none;
  -moz-box-shadow:none;
  box-shadow:none
  }
 header #logo{
  width:435px;
  height:80px;
  background:url(../images/logo/trlogo.png) no-repeat 0 50%
  }
 header.navbar{
  margin-bottom:0
  }
 header.navbar .nav{ margin-top:20px}
 header.navbar .nav>li{margin-left:1px}
 header.navbar .nav>li>a{
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  color:#333;
  font-family:"Fjalla One";
  font-size:14px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-shadow:none
  }
  header.navbar .nav>li>a:hover{
   background:transparent;
   color:#bb0300;
   -webkit-box-shadow:none;
   -moz-box-shadow:none;
   box-shadow:none
   }
  header.navbar .nav>li.active>a,header.navbar .nav>li.active>a:hover{
   background:transparent;
   color:#bb0300;
   -webkit-box-shadow:none;
   -moz-box-shadow:none;
   box-shadow:none
   }
  header.navbar .nav>li.dropdown.open>a.dropdown-toggle{
   background:transparent;
   color:#bb0300
   }
  header.navbar .nav>li.login>a{ border-left:1px solid #e5e5e5 }
  header .dropdown-menu{margin-top:20px; color:#bb0300 }
  header .dropdown-menu:before{display:none!important}
  .navbar .nav li.dropdown.open>.dropdown-toggle,.navbar .nav li.dropdown.active>.dropdown-toggle,.navbar .nav li.dropdown.open.active>.dropdown-toggle{
   background-color:transparent;
   color:#bb0300
   }
  .navbar .nav>.active>a,.navbar .nav>.active>a:hover,.navbar .nav>.active>a:focus{
   -webkit-box-shadow:none;
   -moz-box-shadow:none;
   box-shadow:none
   }
  .navbar .nav>li>a:focus,.navbar .nav>li>a:hover{color:#bb0300}
  .dropdown-menu{-webkit-border-radius:0;-moz-border-radius:0; border-radius:0;-webkit-box-shadow:none;-moz-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;padding:0;border:0}
  .dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-submenu:hover>a,.dropdown-submenu:focus>a{
   background:#bb0300
   }
   .main-info{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#3a3a3a
   }.main-info h4{
    color:#706f6f
   }
   .icon-medium{
    font-size:18px;
    width:18px;
    line-height:18px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#db2323;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:100%;
    -moz-border-radius:100%;
    border-radius:100%;
    color:#fff
    }
   .modal{border:0}
   .modal#loginForm{width:600px;margin-left:-300px}
   .modal .modal-header{border:0;padding:20px 20px 0}
   .modal .modal-header>h4{font-weight:300;font-size:14px;color:#848484;text-transform:uppercase;margin:0}
   .modal .modal-body{padding:20px}
   .modal input[type="text"],.modal input[type="password"]{padding:5px 10px;min-height:30px;width:130px;margin-right:10px}
   .modal .icon-remove{
    color:#848484;
    position:absolute;
    right:-5px;
    top:-5px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    line-height:16px;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    background:#ebebeb;
    -webkit-border-radius:100%;
    -moz-border-radius:100%;
    border-radius:100%;
    cursor:pointer
    }
    .modal button{margin-left:10px;border:0}
    .gap{margin-bottom:50px}
    .big-gap{margin-bottom:100px}
    .no-margin{margin:0;padding:0}
    #services{background:#252525;color:#999}
    #services h1,#services h2,#services h3,#services h4,#services h5,#services h6{color:#fff}
    #main-contents{margin-top:20px}
    #main-contents .blog-news .created{font-size:18px;color:#2dcc70}
    .registration-form{
     border:0;
     background-color:#fff;
     border-top:1px solid #f0f0f0;
     -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     box-shadow:0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     padding:20px;
     display:inline-block}#bottom{background:#000000;
     color:#6f6f6f
     }
     #bottom h4{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:15px}
     #bottom h1,#bottom h2,#bottom h3,#bottom h4,#bottom h5,#bottom h6{color:#fff}
     #bottom a{color:#6f6f6f}
     #bottom a:hover{color:#2dcc70}
     #bottom ul.address>li{position:relative;padding-left:20px;margin-top:10px}
     #bottom ul.address>li:first-child{margin-top:0}
     #bottom ul.address>li>i{position:absolute;top:3px;left:0}
     #bottom ul.thumbnails{margin-bottom:0}
     #bottom ul.thumbnails li{
      margin-bottom:5px;
      }
      ul.arrow,ul.arrow-double,ul.tick,ul.cross,ul.star,ul.rss{
       list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;
      }
      ul.arrow li::before,ul.arrow-double li::before,ul.tick li::before,ul.cross li::before,ul.star li::before,ul.rss li::before,ul.arrow li::after,ul.arrow-double li::after,ul.tick li::after,ul.cross li::after,ul.star li::after,ul.rss 
      li::after{
       font-family:FontAwesome;
       font-size:11px;
       }
      ul.arrow li::before,ul.arrow-double li::before,ul.tick li::before,ul.cross li::before,ul.star li::before,ul.rss li::before{margin-right:5px}
      ul.arrow li::before{content:"\f105"}
      ul.arrow-double li::before{content:"\f101"}
      ul.tick li::before{content:"\f00c"}
      ul.cross li::before{content:"\f00d"}
      ul.star li::before{content:"\f006"}
      ul.rss li::before{content:"\f09e"}
      #footer{
       background:#333;
       padding-top:15px;
       padding-bottom:15px;
       color:#666;
      }
      #footer a{color:#666}
      #footer a:hover{color:#ef0909}
      #footer #gototop{height:40px;
      line-height:40px;
      width:40px;
      text-align:center;
      display:inline-block;
      background:#1d1d1d;
      font-size:24px;
      color:#fff;
      }
      #footer #gototop:hover{
       background:#bb0000;
       text-decoration:none;
      }
      #footer .cp{
       margin-top:11px;
       }
      ul.social{
       list-style:none;
       margin:10px 0 0;
       padding:0;
       display:inline-block;
      }
      ul.social>li{
       display:inline-block;
       margin:0 5px;
      }
      ul.social>li>a{
       font-size:24px;
       color:#666;
      }
      ul.social>li>a:hover{
       color:#999;
      }.box-border{
       padding:15px;
      }.accordion-group{
       background-color:#fff;
       border-top:1px solid #f0f0f0;
      }.accordion-heading .accordion-toggle{
      color:#666;
      font-weight:700;
      }
      .accordion-inner{border-top:0}
      .blog .blog-item h2{margin-top:0}
      .blog .blog-item .date span{display:block;text-align:center}
      .blog .blog-item .date span.day{
       font-size:50px;
       line-height:50px;
       padding-top:10px;
       font-family:"Fjalla One",sans-serif;
      }
      .blog .blog-item .date span.month{font-size:18px}
      .blog .blog-item .tag{margin-top:5px}
      .blog .blog-item .avatar{margin-top:5px}
      select,textarea,input[type="text"],
      input[type="password"],
      input[type="datetime"],
      input[type="datetime-local"],
      input[type="date"],
      input[type="month"],
      input[type="time"],
      input[type="week"],
      input[type="number"],
      input[type="email"],
      input[type="url"],
      input[type="search"],
      input[type="tel"],
      input[type="color"],
      .uneditable-input{-webkit-border-radius:3px;
       -moz-border-radius:3px;
       border-radius:3px;
       -webkit-box-shadow:none;
       -moz-box-shadow:none;
       box-shadow:none;
       min-height:50px;
       padding:0 15px;
       border:3px solid #ededed
      }
      select:focus,textarea:focus,
      input[type="text"]:focus,
      input[type="password"]:focus,
      input[type="datetime"]:focus,
      input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,
      input[type="date"]:focus,
      input[type="month"]:focus,
      input[type="time"]:focus,
      input[type="week"]:focus,
      input[type="number"]:focus,
      input[type="email"]:focus,
      input[type="url"]:focus,
      input[type="search"]:focus,
      input[type="tel"]:focus,
      input[type="color"]:focus,
      .uneditable-input:focus{
       border-color:#2dcc70;
       -webkit-box-shadow:none;
       -moz-box-shadow:none;
       box-shadow:none;
      }
      .input-block-level{
       min-height:50px;
      }
      textarea#message{
       padding:10px 15px;
       height:305px;
      }
      .widget{
       margin-bottom:30px;
      }
      .widget>h3{
       font-size:16px;
       margin-top:0;
      }
      .widget h5{
       margin-top:10px;
      }.widget .date{
       margin-top:5px;
       padding:8px 10px;
       background:#2dcc70;
      }.widget .date>span{
       display:block;
       text-align:center;
       font-family:"Fjalla One";
       color:#fff;
      }.widget .date>span.month{
       font-size:14px;
       line-height:14px;
       font-weight:700;
       text-transform:uppercase;
      }.widget .date>span.day{
       font-size:18px;
       line-height:18px;
      }#pricing-table{
       margin-top:20px;
       margin-bottom:30px;
      }#pricing-table .plan{
       list-style:none;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       color:#fff;
      }#pricing-table .plan.featured{
       -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
       -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
       -ms-transform:scale(1.1);
       -o-transform:scale(1.1);
       transform:scale(1.1);
      }
      #pricing-table .plan>li{padding:10px 15px}
      #pricing-table .plan>li.plan-name{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1)}
      #pricing-table .plan>li.plan-name h3{margin:10px 0}
      #pricing-table .plan>li.plan-action{padding:20px 0}
      #pricing-table .plan1{background:#1abc9c}
      #pricing-table .plan2{background:#e74c3c}
      #pricing-table .plan3{background:#3498db}
      #pricing-table .plan4{background:#9b59b6}
      ul.gallery{display:block;margin:-15px}
      ul.gallery.col-1 li{width:100%}
      ul.gallery.col-2 li{width:50%}
      ul.gallery.col-3 li{width:33.3333%}
      ul.gallery.col-4 li{width:25%}
      ul.gallery li{display:block;padding:0;margin:0;float:left}
      ul.gallery li .desc{margin:15px}
      ul.gallery li .preview{margin:15px;display:block;position:relative}
      ul.gallery li .preview .overlay{
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
       position:absolute;
       left:0;top:0;
       background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
       opacity:0;
       filter:alpha(opacity=0);
       -webkit-transition:opacity 300ms;
       -moz-transition:opacity 300ms;
       -o-transition:opacity 300ms;
       transition:opacity 300ms;
      }
      ul.gallery li .preview modal-bodyinks{
       width:104px;
       height:40px;
       position:absolute;
       top:50%;
       left:50%;
       margin-top:-20px;
       margin-left:-52px;
       opacity:0;
       filter:alpha(opacity=0);
       -webkit-transform:translate(0,-50px);
       -moz-transform:translate(0,-50px);
       -ms-transform:translate(0,-50px);
       -o-transform:translate(0,-50px);
       transform:translate(0,-50px);
       -webkit-transition:300ms;
       -moz-transition:300ms;
       -o-transition:300ms;
       transition:300ms
      }
      ul.gallery li .preview .links>a{
       width:50px;
       height:40px;
       line-height:40px;
       display:inline-block;
       text-align:center;
       background:#2dcc70;
       color:#fff;
       text-shadow:0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
       font-size:18px;
       margin:0 1px;
      }
      ul.gallery li .preview:hover .overlay,ul.gallery li .preview:hover .links{
       opacity:1;
       filter:alpha(opacity=100)
      }
      ul.gallery li .preview:hover .links{
       -webkit-transform:translate(0,0);
       -moz-transform:translate(0,0);
       -ms-transform:translate(0,0);
       -o-transform:translate(0,0);
       transform:translate(0,0);
      }
      ul.faq{
       list-style:none;
       margin:0;
      }
      ul.faq li{
       margin-top:30px;
      }
      ul.faq li:first-child{margin-top:0}
      ul.faq li span.number{
       display:block;
       float:left;
       width:50px;
       height:50px;
       line-height:50px;
       text-align:center;
       background:#bb0300;
       color:#fff;font-size:24px;
      }ul.faq li>div{margin-left:70px}ul.faq li>div h3{margin-top:0}#error{text-align:center;margin-top:150px;margin-bottom:150px}
  #mapSection, #carouselSection{border-top:0px solid #BB0000; border-bottom: 0px; background: #bb0300; color:#fff}

  .container1{width:1170px; margin-right:0px; }
  .input-block-level1{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 min-height:30px;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box
 }
  .input-block-level1{min-height:50px}textarea#message1 { padding:10px 15px; height:220px}
```

Comment: you have to post a working snippet!

Comment: You probably have a child element with a fixed width set, or an element whose defaults are wider than 320px (tables are notorious offenders for this). Either keep looking or post a working snippet so we can take a look.

Comment: I did post it. Thank you.

Comment: @Max please use screenshots..not cam pics.

Comment: You've posted your CSS only, you have to post your HTML as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet isn't working - you'd need to add the html to have help debugging this specific case.

However, the key to solving this problem (and others like it - they will come up all the time if you're working with HTML/CSS) will be in learning how to debug the HTML/CSS for yourself - the best approach will be to learn how to use 'inspect element' or 'Firefox Developer Browser' with Firefox or 'chrome-devtools' in Chrome. Some articles to help:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector